# Apple Login with Flutter and Firebase is not saving the private relay emails

Tags: flutter, firebase, apple-login

###### We are allowing login via Apple in our Flutter/Firebase app.

Following [these instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple) we have enabled apple as a sign in provider:

[image]

The sign in via apple all works fine,
However we are not getting the private relay email saved in the Authentication in Firebase,
instead it is coming through as null:

[image]

#### What do we need so that the private relay email comes through via an Apple sign up?

Answer (score 1):

The email is found in the additionalUserInfo when signing in. I haven't found a way yet to let firebase set the email and I the only way I found, was to set it manually like this:

```
final userCredential = await auth.signInWithProvider(
          AppleAuthProvider().addScope('email'),
        );
final email = userCredential.additionalUserInfo?.profile?['email'] as String;
userCredential.user?.verifyBeforeUpdateEmail(email);
```

This of course implies that a verification email with link is sent, on which the user has to click.

Comment: Ok, it seems I've encountered a strange bug here. It seems to be enough to add the
`AppleAuthProvider().addScope('email')` part